# Baggage storage in downtown Toronto

Tags: luggage-storage, toronto

I am traveling to Toronto, ON, Canada in July with my family. We will arrive at around 1 am and we plan to take some rest until around 9 am in the airport and then travel downtown.

However, the place we are going to stay at during the vacation has a kind of late check-in time, at 5 pm. We'd like to ditch the luggage during the day and pick it up before we check in the accommodation.

Is there any luggage storage service or baggage locker in downtown Toronto, which is in a fair price range for one-day storage?

Comment: Depending on the type of accomodation you are staying in, they may be happy to take your luggage off you early, even if you can't check in yet. (Most hotels would, just as they look after the luggage of those who have checked out already)

Comment: We are staying in a AirBnB but the host hasn't answered whether we can drop the luggage before check-in time yet. So I'm asking in case they prefer not.

Comment: One of the unfortunate side-effects of the AirBnB business model, there is often no "staff" on-site to handle these types of exceptions.

Comment: Would the hotel not be able to store your luggage prior to check-in? Doesn't hurt to ask ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store luggage at the Toronto Coach Terminal, i.e. the bus station.  They still have luggage-lockers there last time I was there (spring 2015).

[image: Toronto Coach Terminal luggage lockers]
[Source: Yelp](https://www.yelp.ca/biz/toronto-coach-terminal-toronto)

Comment: In the end I didn't use the locker but I went to the terminal when I was walking by. The terminal is accessible by streetcar, within walking distance (around 15 minutes if you're carrying luggage) from St. Patrick station and PATH underground foot tunnel system. Take note that the lockers were aged and there are many with broken locks. When I visited here in the evening, almost all lockers were occupied.

Answer (score 12):

The intercontinental hotel next to Union Station will store luggage for non-guests for $3 per item [ed: $5 as of June 2018, cash only]. I know this won't be much use to the original poster but its hopefully useful to anyone Googles the same question in future.

Answer (score 6):

The royal Ontario museum cloakroom accepts luggage.
It will cost five dollars as long as museum open.

Comment: Does the museum cloakroom accept a full amount of holiday luggage and do they allow you to leave your things there while you leave the museum or only as long as you are in?

Answer (score 4):

There is a mobile storage company that caters to downtown Toronto called [BagsAway](http://www.bagsaway.ca/). I think they are fairly new (can't find much on a Google search) but I have used them and the staff seemed friendly and professional.

They picked up my luggage from my Airbnb at 10am as per my request and delivered it back to my Airbnb at 5pm before I made my way to the airport. Price was not that cheap, $8 for the first bag and $5 for additional bags. I couldn't find any other options for luggage storage that was convenient enough to use. Service was great and allowed me to enjoy my last day in Toronto.

Comment: We booked and paid for Bagsaway to store our luggage in Toronto months prior to travelling only to receive a phone call 48hrs prior saying they cant help us, refund pending

Answer (score 4):

Downtown, the InterContinental Toronto Centre Hotel (225 Front Street West) stores bags for $3 each per day. Bonus: it is next to Union Station, which has a direct train to the airport.

Comment: Commenting that in name of [nik0lla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/66697/nik0lla), who did not have enough reputation to comment: InterContinental Toronto Centre Hotel" will only do luggage hold for guests (called to confirm).

Answer (score 2):

You can store your baggage at Toronto Coach Station (departures terminal) for 24 hours. However you are unable to say when those 24 hours started or ended. Vending machines for tokens take only $5 bills. You can fit two carry-on backpacks into one locker. If your token is stuck in the locker, try to find a security guy who will be able to take it out without buying a new one. (June 2018)

Answer (score -1):

lockers in greycoach bus terminal in central Toronto are exactly timed to 24 hours max.
luggage will be removed by staff as needed. you cannot get your luggage back once the timer runs out until you pay for every minute overdue.

also, no one is ever able to tell you how much time is left.